# what is the meaning of "? :" operator PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand this:

```
$page = isset($requestvars['page']) ? $requestvars['page'] : 1;

$product = isset($requestvars['product']) ? $requestvars['product'] : ''
```

But I don't comprehend what "?" does..This would be like a simple if?

Thanks

Comment: `?` means if. `:` means else

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: is this true `?` Yes! `:` No :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), and essentially replaces an `if else` block.

For example:

```
$page = isset($requestvars['page']) ? $requestvars['page'] : 1;
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
if(isset($requestvars['page']))
{
    $page = $requestvars['page'];
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}
```

The ternary operator tells PHP to assign `$requestvars['page']` to `$page` if the value is set, otherwise to assign `1`.

Comment: Wow you type extremely fast. I was only half way through... and now I've just realised you made an edit on his post too. Sad :( +1 still.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It works like an if statement, but it's shorter.

```
echo ($a === true) ? 'yep' : 'nope';
```

Since PHP 5.3, there's also a shortest version, the `?:` operator, which only tests the expression and return the expression itself in case of success, or the other option otherwise.

```
$foo = getSomethingFromTheDb();
$default = new stdObject;

$object = $foo ?: $default;
```

Answer (score 0):

The is a ternary expression.

It is much more clearly displayed as an if/else, but some people really like them.

Comment: Most people like them because of their small footprint, and inline-ability.

Comment: Yeah, but they can make easy to understand code very dense when badly used. Style being what it is, I tend to just smile and nod at them.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a Ternary operation. It is basically an inline if.

```
$product = isset($variable) ? do something if true : do something if false;
```

They are just short forms for writing an inline if. Very useful for keeping clean code when testing.